# Changing chord group while group tasks are already running

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd, chord

I'm running the following `chord` in my periodic task:

```
(group(task_A1, task_A2, ... , task_An) | task_B)
```

Each of tasks (`task_A1`, `task_A2` ... , `task_An`) may take ~5-10 min to run.

Consider the following scenario:
During a periodic task (hourly),`task_A1` .. `task_An` are running in parallel. Now, from another flow someone triggered an external `task_A1'` task. My goal is to stop & replace only the current running `task_A1` with `task_A1'` and keep (without stopping `task_A2`.. `task_An`) the flow as is - which is to wait for the group (of `task_A2, ... ,task_An` & the new `task_A1'`) to finish and to start the `task_B`.

My current solution is to revoke `task_A1` & `task_B` and add new tasks `task_A1'` & `task_B'` to queues - but I wonder how to be create this new 
combination with the already running `task_A2, ... , task_An`, to achieve something like:

```
(group(task_A1', task_A2, ... , task_An) | task_B')
```

I'm doing that by revoking tasks and "rewire" them in CeleryRouter. I'm pulling the tasks from `celeryapp.control.inspect().active()` and `celeryapp.control.inspect().reserved()`. I wonder if there is elegant way to get my goal.

Thanks.